# How to search a specific test in cognos query and create filter using that

Tags: cognos

from the below string looking for help to locate text "Mars [L5]" and create filter using cognos query. Say the data item is [kingdom] which has different path in the same format as below.

12345- | Baba [A1]|Other / Etc [A2]|Animal [A3]|Human [A4]|Mars [A5]|Alien [L6]|Mammal

appreciate help.

Comment: What have you tried already and what results did you get?

Comment: Im new to cognos. However I tried using substring and position function and was able to remove all text before Mars but not later. Thanks

Comment: "filter" indicates you want to know simply if the value contains the search term, then that row of data is included in your output.  Locating the text in the search term in the string value (Return an integer value indicating at which character the search term starts within the value.) is a completely different effort.  Which is it you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data base, some variation of LIKE, CONTAINS, or LIKE_REGEX would be helpful I think.

I'm not sure why you think you need to use substring and position.  I would use those in excel if I wanted to get some substring which I would want in another cell but you say you want to do a filter. It is possible that your use of the term filter has contributed to a mistaken problem definition.

I would suggest that you read up a bit on SQL.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_syntax

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database, if you want to remove all text after Mars

Let's say the data item we are working with is called **MyDataItem**

1. If you want this to be dynamic, we can create a text box prompt, in this example with the parameter **MyTest**
2. Create a data item called **LengthOfMyTest**
   with the expression:

`Len(trim(?MyTest?)) +1`

3. Then we can create another data item called **MyDataItemRevised**
   With an expression like this:

`case`

`when (locate(?MyTest?, [MyDataItem]) > 0)then(`

`substring([MyDataItem], locate(?MyTest?, [MyDataItem]) + [LengthOfMyTest])`

`)else([MyDataItem])`

`end`

If we just wanted to hardcode for Mars:
Locate will return a position if it finds a match
The first "when" statement checks to see if there is anything with Mars
If so it substrings starting from the result of the locate function plus the length of mars and +1 for the space

Otherwise, just return the whole data item

```
case 
when (locate('Mars ', [MyDataItem]) > 0)then( substr([MyDataItem],locate('Mars ', [MyDataItem]) +5)) 
else([MyDataItem]) 
end
```